# Creating a dataset.designer.vb from XSD

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, xsd, dataset, designer

I have an `.xsd`, `.vb`, `.xsc`, and `.xss` file for a dataset in Visual Studio 2008 that I copied over from another Visual Studio project, however I need to make changes to the dataset. Thus I got into the XSD file, created new columns, deleted ones that aren't needed, etc., etc.  However I realized when I attempted to use the new dataset I did not have the Visual Basic code behind the scenes. This code is typically found in `dataset.designer.vb`. When I copied the old one over of course it was no longer valid since columns changed.

How I can force Visual Studio 2008 to use a `.xsd` file and to have it create/update its designer code?

Comment: How was the original XSD generated? Was it through a Data Source that was connected to a database?

Answer (score 8):

You just have to exclude your `.xsd` file and include it again. It will regenerate your `designer.vb` file.

Comment: like @lamsland's answer said...   Click the .xsd file in Solution Explorer. Update the "Custom Tool" property to "MSDataSetGenerator".

Comment: Worked for me while the other solutions above did not.

Comment: Ok, that's a big thank you-saved me another several hours figuring out!

Comment: I was getting crazy....thx Bro!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is still a common problem for others, but I did find an answer (I think). Click the .xsd file in Solution Explorer.  Update the "Custom Tool" property to "MSDataSetGenerator".  This will automatically regenerate the *.Designer.vb file.

Comment: I've had several times where the Designer file got jacked up when moving or renaming files.  I always had to play around in the solution until the files were fixed.  This did the trick on the first try.

Comment: Which property I have to set to generate vb classes file?

Answer (score 3):

You can right click the .xsd file and select **'Run Custom Tool'** to regenerate the dataset.designer.vb file.

Comment: If the 'Run Custom Tool' context menu item is missing, see @lambsland's answer below

Answer (score 1):

THANKS for the help, in the end I JUST was able to get a `dataset.vb` file generated using the `xsd.exe` tool. It works for now, however, I still think something isn't set right in Visual Studio 2008 or at least the "Generate Dataset" menu option from the context menu on an XSD file is gone.

I'll just need to remember that if I modify the XSD file from here on out that Visual Studio isn't updating the `.vb` file automatically, I'll probably get stuck with reusing the `xsd.exe` program.

For others the command is (using Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt Window Tool, in Admin mode if using Windows Vista).

```
xsd.exe /d /l:VB "XSD FILE LOCATION PATH"
```

`/d` means create a dataset code. `/l` is the language.

The `.vb` file will be created in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: cd into the directory where you want the output first, then it will write it there instead of C:\Windows\System32.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is in the gray area of things things that I can do when I need to, but I haven't needed to do enough to impart the knowledge to others.

All I know is that `*.designer.vb` means that this code was generated by Visual Studio, and if it generated it once it can do it again. Additionally, the very few times (maybe twice, both in Visual Studio 2005) that I have done this, it seemed like it was as simple as adding the  *.xsd file to Solution Explorer. If that alone doesn't do it, try showing all files or right/double clicking on the *.xsd.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the extra designer.vb file created when u add the xsd file.